# Using linq to check property against one of multiple possible values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Using linq to check property against one of multiple possible values. In this case when the status is 2 or 3? Can this be done without an or operator?

```
var x = (from b in books
         where b.statusCode.Contains(2, 3))
         select new ...
```

Comment: Your question and your example don't make sense.  Maybe that's because there's no OR operator in your example, and you seem to be mis-using "contains" ?  If you want to check whether statusCode is 2 or 3, then put 2 and 3 in a list and check if that list contains statusCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up the list of values as a `List<int>`, call it something like `ValueList`, and then on your where line:

`where ValueList.Contains(b.statusCode)`

This should compare the `statusCode` against all list values and return the records that match, and you get the benefit of a dynamic list that can be reset with different values to return collections of other status codes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this (assuming that statusCode is int)

```
var values = new int[] { 2, 3 };

var x = (from b in books
     where values.Contains(b.statusCode))
     select new ...
```

or You can try to inline it like that:

```
    var x = (from b in books
     where (new int[] { 2, 3 }.Contains(b.statusCode)))
     select new ...
```